Perform fsutil command always reports "The parameter is incorrect" in Win11
I met a Win11 update problem with 0x80071a91 error code. And I did some research from internet. In all the solutions, the first solution is always to reset the FSRM service. But when I perform the command fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\, it always reports error "The parameter is incorrect". Is there a way to fix the problem? I think it's the key to resolve the update problem.

I assume you have ran sfc /scannow? If this “solution” wasn’t suggested since 2012 I would almost say this solution was entirely suggested by ChatGPT. The suggested command makes absolutely no sense.
